# class has no initializers swift in watch

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch

I have added 3rd party library (KBarChart) . i am getting error like this
    class timeInterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

```
     var chartImage: WKInterfaceImage

    override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
        super.awakeWithContext(context)

    }

    override func willActivate() {
        super.willActivate()

        var image: UIImage
        var frame:CGRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.contentFrame.size.width, self.contentFrame.size.height)

        var chart:KBarChart = NKBarChart(frame: frame)
        chart.yLabelFormatter = {(yValue: CGFloat) in    var yValueParsed: CGFloat = yValue
}enter code here

I am getting error like
```

Can any one help me out.. how to resolve ?

[image: Can any one help me out]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I should comment or answer, since I can't answer the whole question, but I can provide a partial answer. The reason it's saying your class has no initializer is because you have a non-optional var in your class. If you make that optional, that error will go away. I'm afraid I don't know what kBarChart is, so I can't help you there.

Edit:

I just noticed the initializer you use to initialize chart is of type `NKBarChart`, so maybe you were trying to have chart be of type `NKBarChart` rather than `KBarChart`. Also, you don't need to declare the type of the variable since the compiler can infer it in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I can answer the other Part. There seems to be a typo in this line

```
var chart:KBarChart = NKBarChart(frame: frame)
```

It should be

```
var chart:NKBarChart = NKBarChart(frame: frame)
```